# git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges with merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I am currently purging passwords and other sensitive data from a git repository. I would like to preserve the history as much as possible, including merges. So I am doing `git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges <commit>`. Then I edit the instructions to edit the specific commits that I care about. During the rebase, I am surprised to see merge conflicts not related to my password editing. I believe these are conflicts that occurred with some of the existing merges in the history and were resolved at the time of the merge. Why isn't git able to just replay the commit that resolved these conflicts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`--preserve-merges` isn't compatible with `--interactive`.**

(All the quotes in this answer are from `git help rebase`.)

> This uses the --interactive machinery internally, but combining it with the `--interactive` option explicitly is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).

and

> In addition, the following pairs of options are incompatible:
>
> - `--preserve-merges` and `--interactive`

#### use `--rebase-merges` instead

`--rebase-merges` was [introduced in Git 2.18](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.21.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.18.0.txt#L98-L99) and `--preserve-merges` was officially [deprecated in Git 2.22](https://github.blog/2019-06-07-highlights-from-git-2-22/#rebase-merges-interactively).

> The `--rebase-merges` mode is similar in spirit to the deprecated `--preserve-merges` but works with interactive rebases, where commits can be reordered, inserted and dropped at will.

It still may not solve your problem:

> **Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.**

Even if it doesn't solve your problem, I think it definitively answers your question. Plus, you should be using this option anyway as `--preserve-merges` is now deprecated.

There are more `git help rebase` comments on `--rebase-merges`. I recommend reading them.

Comment: What version introduces `--rebase-merges`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice updated answer with version info. BTW, did you still have to deal with the merge conflicts all over again?

Comment: I'm not sure why you edited my question. Most of your edit changed my question in a way that modifies the question from my original intent.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I write for a living. The title because it doesn't state any problem (i.e. the merge conflicts were unexpected). It's more like a topic. Imagine if the title were "git rebase --interactive with merge conflicts"... that's something that just happens, is not a problem or question. Maybe it's why it hasn't seen much traffic in 2.5 years. In the body, I just cleaned up some wordiness ("still", "to edit the specific commits that I care about" which is unnecessary since that's the point of `rebase -i`)... I'm not sure how that changes the intent at all, but ‍♂️.

Comment: I disagree that the title needs to be a question. IMO it should be a succinct description of the problem that can be easily understood when it displays on a Google search. With that said, I think you correctly added the `--interactive` flag which is a key part of the problem that I asked about.

Comment: I also agree that the word "still" isn't needed. At the same time, your edit added some run-on sentences that weren't part of my original wording.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges with merge conflicts" doesn't read as a problem to me at all. Merge conflicts are normal. Your issue is that the ones you got weren't expected, because they were previously handled and those resolutions should have been reapplied (git `rerere`). Anyways, don't want to debate this further.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think we have improved this from what it was. I'm also ready to move on.